# Is there a Yum command equivalent to rpm -qf filename.repo?

Tags: linux, centos, yum

`rpm` can deliver the package name of a given `.repo` file.

For example:

```
rpm -qf epel.repo
epel-release-7-11.noarch
```

Is there a `yum` equivalent?  I've done quite a bit of searching and everyone points to the `rpm` command, but never a `yum` version.

`yum --help` doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**yum provides** is very close to **rpm -qf** , but yum can search in non-installed packages . rpm will search only on installed package .

```
[user@whome.local ~]$ yum provides /usr/bin/alien
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Repodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.lstn.net
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirror.lstn.net
 * extras: repos-tx.psychz.net
 * updates: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
alien-8.95-3.el7.noarch : Converter between the rpm, dpkg, stampede slp, and Slackware tgz file formats
Repo        : epel
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/alien



[user@home.local ~]$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/alien
error: file /usr/bin/alien: No such file or directory
```